# Prove that $n$ x $n$ matrix A is a semimagic square if and only if.....

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Prove that $n$ x $n$ matrix A is a semimagic square if and only if the vector $$x = [1     1   1...1]  $$ (every entry is 1) is an eigenvector of both A and $A^T$ with the same eigenvalue.

I started by letting $$ A = 
        \begin{matrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & a+b+c-d-e \\
        b+c-d & a+c-e & -c+d-e \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

and assuming $$x = [1     1   1...1]  $$ is an eigenvector and showing there exists an eigenvalue

I calculated Ax to find that the eigenvalue $= (a,b,c)$ and showed the same for $A^T$

I know because it says "if and only if" i need to show both ways but i'm not sure how to prove the other way

Comment: Hint: write down the result of multiplying $x$ by $A$ in terms of entries of $A$. What are the components of the resulting vector? Repeat for $A^T$.

Comment: Aren't all the components a+b+c?

Comment: Indeed. Can you see how does it prove the theorem in one direction?

Comment: Yes, is it not a good idea to prove using a specific example (like the 3x3 matrix i have shown), because it says for all semi-magic squares and i suppose if i prove it like this i'm just showing it is true for 3x3 matrices. How would i extend this to all nxn matrices?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably worth saying what a "semi-magic square" is: I googled it just now, and apparently it's a matrix whose rows and columns all sum to the same number.

You've tried setting up your matrix to force it to be a semi-magic square with a the rows and columns summing to $e$, but this looks like it's just obscuring what's really happening.

Instead, just consider the products

$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & \ddots &   & a_{2n} \\ \vdots & &\ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

and

$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ a_{21} & \ddots &   & a_{2n} \\ \vdots & &\ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & a_{nn} \end{pmatrix}^\top \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $$

What do they represent?  This should let you prove the theorem in both directions at once.

Comment: So, Ax represents the sum of the rows and $A^T$ represents the sum of the columns.

Comment: How do i proceed to prove the other direction? Do i try to show that with an eigenvector $x$ and eigenvalues that are the same for $A$ and $A^T$ that the matrix is semimagic?

Comment: You've already done both directions!